# Custom Histogram Normalization in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to make a normalized histogram in matplotlib, however I want it normalized such that the total area will be 1000. Is there a way to do this?

I know to get it normalized to 1, you just have to include `density=True,stacked=True` in the argument of `plt.hist()`. An equivalent solution would be to do this and multiply the height of each column by 1000, if that would be more doable than changing what the histogram is normalized to.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach uses `np.histogram` to calculate the counts for each histogram bin. Using `1000 / total_count / bin_width` as normalization factor, the total area will be 1000. On the contrary, to get the sum of all bar heights to be 1000, a factor of `1000 / total_count` would be needed.
`plt.bar` is used to display the end result.

The example code calculates the same combined histogram with `density=True,` to compare it with the new histogram summing to 1000.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [np.random.randn(100) * 5 + 10, np.random.randn(300) * 4 + 14, np.random.randn(100) * 3 + 17]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

ax1.hist(data, stacked=True, density=True)
ax1.set_title('Histogram with density=True')

xmin = min([min(d) for d in data])
xmax = max([max(d) for d in data])
bins = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 11)
bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]

counts = [np.histogram(d, bins=bins)[0] for d in data]
total_count = sum([sum(c) for c in counts])
# factor = 1000 / total_count # to sum to 1000
factor = 1000 / total_count / bin_width # for an area of 1000
thousands = [c * factor for c in counts]

bottom = 0
for t in thousands:
    ax2.bar(bins[:-1], t, bottom=bottom, width=bin_width, align='edge')
    bottom += t
ax2.set_title('Histogram with total area of 1000')

plt.show()
```

[image: stacked histogram summing to 1000]

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to set up a second y-axis whose tick labels are the original multiplied by 1000, then hide the original axis' ticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [np.random.randn(5000)]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

#hist returns a tuple that contains a list of y values at its 0 index:
y,_,_ = ax1.hist(data, density=True, bins=10, edgecolor = 'black')

#find max y value of histogram and multiply by 1000:
max_y = np.round(y.max(),1)*1000

#set up the second y-axis ticks as increments of max_y:
ax2.set_ylim(0,max_y)
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, max_y, 9))

#hide original y-axis ticks:
ax1.axes.yaxis.set_ticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing things is using weights.

plt.hist() has the optional keyword weights, if you use an array of the same shape as your data with 1000 (sth like `weights= 1000 * np.ones(data.size)`) as every entry you effectively multiply each column by 1000.

Sorry for no code example, don't have time and don't have the reputation to leave a comment :-(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).